# Curl to grab remote filename and extension with php and finally output to browser

Tags: php, curl

When downloading a file using curl, how would I follow a link location and use that for the output filename (without knowing the remote filename and extension in advance)?

For example, if one clicks on the link below, you would download a filenamed "dam.zip."

> http://www.your-site.com/download.php?src_id=5896

It would be excellent if you could download the file without knowing the name and the extension in advance and force download at same time. Please help me